# How can I add a custom reporter to Jasmine through karma?

Tags: karma-jasmine

I'm trying to call jasmine-fail-fast through karma. I have karma-jasmine installed.

[https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-fail-fast][1]

All jasmine custom reporters appear to have a configuration like the one below to add it.

```
var failFast = require('jasmine-fail-fast');
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(failFast.init());
```

The problem is that this does not work in my karma.conf:

```
module.exports = function(options) {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(failFast.init());

    config.set({...});
};
```

The karma.conf file does not give me access to jasmine or window.jasmine through module.exports

The karma config itself can give a require in jasmine-fail-fast for me if I add it as a plugin:

```
plugins: ['karma-firefox-launcher', 'karma-jasmine', 'jasmine-fail-fast'],
```

But unfortunately it never calls the init():

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(failFast.init());
```

Does anyone know how the hell I can add this reporter to jasmine with karma?

[1]: jasmine-fail-fast Causes Jasmine to stop after failing the first test

Comment: Have you solved this issue? And how? I met exactly the same and am lost probably as you were...